# Strange behavior of One Class SVM in sklearn

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am using one class SVM on a personal dataset. 
This is the code that I am using:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(X0)
X_pca = pca.transform(X0)




X = X_pca

X = X/X.max()
X = sk.preprocessing.scale(X)

n_new = 1641
n_normal = 500
x_normal = X[:n_normal]
x_new = X[:n_new]

n, p = X.shape
svm = OneClassSVM(kernel='rbf', degree=2, gamma=0.0, coef0=0.0, tol=0.001, 
                  nu=.1, shrinking=True, cache_size=200, verbose=False, 
                  max_iter=-1, random_state=None)
svm.fit(x_normal)
anomaly = svm.predict(x_new)
anomaly_score = - svm.decision_function(x_new)
anomaly_normal = svm.predict(x_normal)
anomaly_score_normal = - svm.decision_function(x_normal)


xx1, yy1 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2, 2, 1000), np.linspace(-2, 2, 1000))

Z1 = svm.decision_function(np.c_[xx1.ravel(), yy1.ravel()])
Z1 = Z1.reshape(xx1.shape)

nrow = 2
i = 1
plt.subplot(nrow, 1, i)
plt.scatter(x_normal[:, 0], x_normal[:, 1], c=anomaly_score_normal)
plt.colorbar()
plt.contour( xx1, yy1, Z1, levels=[0], linewidths=2, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
i += 1
plt.subplot(nrow, 1, i)
plt.scatter(x_new[:, 0], x_new[:, 1], c=anomaly_score)
plt.colorbar()
plt.contour( xx1, yy1, Z1, levels=[0], linewidths=2, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
plt.show()
```

I obtain a plot like:
[image]

and I do not understand why the points in the lower left side of the plot are colored in blue while the distance of these points from the decision boundary is much larger than the distance of some yellow points.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you include your training set into x_new on purpose? Can you provide a contour plot with all levels? And can you make sure that the x and y axis are on the same scale in the plot?

Comment: Btw, so the OneClassSVM will do a density estimate basted on spherical RBF. If you want to fit an ellipse, using EllipticEnvelope might be better.

Comment: @AndreasMueller I have included the train set into x_new on purpose to see the differences with the new data. I do not want to fit an ellipse because my data may be more complex. The point that are in lower left side are known to be very different from all the rest of the data. I was expecting them to be much more distant from the border than all the rest. I will upload a picture where the axis have the same scale

Comment: It is probably solved. The reason is that there is another circle around the blue points but this was not visualized in the plot